# Align Buttons to the next line in SAP UI5 "SimpleForm"

Tags: sapui5

I am a newbie in SAPUI5 ;) just started learning the basics. I want to know from you guys how can i align the buttons to the next line / row in the form. As you can see in the below image, Save & Cancel button are aligned to Pin-Code. So let me know. Here is the fiddle link : [jsBin](https://jsbin.com/muzuwikojo/1)

```
var oForm = new sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleForm({
            title: "Sample Form",
            editable: true,
            layout: sap.ui.layout.form.SimpleFormLayout.ResponsiveGridLayout,
            content: [
                new sap.m.Label({ text:"Name" }),
                new sap.m.Input({ placeholder:"Enter name here", width: "60%" }),

                new sap.m.Label({ text:"Company" }),
                new sap.m.Input({ placeholder: "InkYourCode", width: "60%" }),

                new sap.m.Label({ text:"Email"}),
                new sap.m.Input({ placeholder: "Enter email here", width: "60%" }),

                new sap.m.Label({ text:"Mobile"}),
                new sap.m.Input({ placeholder: "Enter Mobile here", width: "60%" }),

                new sap.m.Label({ text: "Pin Code" }),
                new sap.m.Input({ placeholder: "Enter Pin-Code here", width: "60%" }),

                new sap.m.Button({ text: "Save" }),
                new sap.m.Button({ text: "Cancel" })
            ]
        }).placeAt("content");
```

Also can one please tell me what is the meaning of this attribute, I have read the documentation but didn't quite got much hold of it. The terms are as follows : labelSpanXL, labelSpanL, labelSpanM, labelSpanS, emptySpanXL, emptySpanL, emptySpanM, emptySpanS, columnsXL, columnsL, columnsM, breakpointXL, breakpointL & breakpointM.

Answer (score 0):

Screen is divided into span, so we have 12 span in all devices (mobile ,laptop , desktop) so labelspanxl means extra large screen , labelspanl means large screen and so on ... So depending on device your from will display contents.

Comment: Thanks @inlovesap for ur reply... So while desigining the form i need to set values in all attributes XL, L & S ?